# dynamically set css file name in _layout master page in Razor Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a css file referenced in my _layout.cshtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//css/styles-640.css" />
```

there are 2 different versions (640 and 720) for displaying the page in different sizes

The size is a value in the querystring

How can I read the value from the querystring and dynamically inject it into the filename of the .css file?

This is in the master page (_layout.cshtml) and it obviously has lots of different ViewModels depending on which view is being rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if(Request["size"] == 640) {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//css/styles-640.css" />
} else {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//css/styles-720.css" />
}
```

Comment: VS Compiler reports me error: Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Comment: @misak in this case, "size" is being passed as a string, so compare as a string : `@if(Request["size"] == "640") {`.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, Use condition **@if** in _layout.cshtml. Don't remember call cast function.

Request.QueryString["big"] and Request["big"] are same

```
@if (Request.QueryString["big"].AsBool()==true)
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//css/styles-720.css" />

}
else
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//css/styles-640.css" />
}
```